# dart pub get fails to resolve dependencies

Tags: dart

Version: 1.30.0 (system setup)
Commit: c6e592b2b5770e40a98cb9c2715a8ef89aec3d74
Date: 2018-12-11T22:29:11.253Z
Electron: 2.0.12
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
OS: Windows_NT x64 6.1.7601

Dart VM version: 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297 
(Thu Nov 8 23:00:07 2018 +0100) on "windows_x64"

[Dart_Reformatter] pub get
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.

Because Dart_Reformatter depends on stagehand >=3.1.4 which requires SDK version >=2.1.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
exit code 1

I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a version of Dart (or Flutter) where the Dart SDK is `>=2.1.0` – in semver, `2.1.0-dev...` is < `2.1.0`.

Try `flutter upgrade`?